# 'at' command on Suse SLES 11 does nothing, works perfectly on other (RHEL) server

Tags: linux, scheduling, at-command, suse, sles

When our users want to schedule a job using the at command it doesn't work on our SLES 11 server.
If they do the exact same on our RedHat Enterprise Linux server it works perfectly.

I've tested it on both servers with their account:

```
at 11:50
ls -al >/home/USERS/username/justtesting.txt
<<Ctrl+D>>
```

and on the RHEL server it creates that file, and a subsequent atq command gives an empty list.

If I do the exact same on the Suse machine, the file is never created, and the atq command list all attempts we did in the following format:

```
23  2020-03-05 11:50 a USERS\username
```

or

```
24 2020-03-05 11:50 = USERS\username
```

The user is in the etc/at.allow file on the Suse machine (there was no /etc/at.allow or /etc/at.deny file to start with, but I added it anyway), and while scheduling the job there is NO errormessage whatsoever.

If I try the at command as my admin user, it works flawlessly on the SLES machine, so it is probably related to userrights somewhere. But again: the user doesn't get any errormessage indication they don't have the needed permissions.

I have two questions:
First of all, obviously: how do I get this to work? Any help would be greatly appreciated
Second: what does the 'a' or '=' mean in the atq list? If searched but can't seem to find the answer. (the 'at' command is an annoying one to google...   :)  )

best regards, and thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Maybe try this on https://unix.stackexchange.com ?
At a guess I would check things like the user default shell, but you'll get more expertise there

Comment: The documentation says " The format of the output lines (one for each job)
 is: Job number, date, hour, queue, and username."

Comment: maybe a good idea to try it on unix.stackexchange.com. I'm new to this this.

Answer (score 0):

'at' commands are executed by the 'atd' daemon. Check if the daemon is up and running; it seems that default SuSE configuration is set not to run the daemon during startup.

Quick and dirty: `ps ax | grep atd`

More proficiency: `systemctl status atd`

Answer (score 0):

as per suggestion of Andrew, I've posted this question on unix.stackexchange.com.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571490/at-command-on-suse-sles-11-does-nothing-works-perfectly-on-other-rhel-serve